# Recursively draw the oriented tiling of a manifold

Tags: tikz-pgf, lindenmayer

I am trying to recreate the image below using recursion. Is it possible to define Lindenmayer system to recursively nest the arrows?

Sorry for no MWE as I have no idea where to start, except to draw the figures manually.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what is your recursion. Probably you want the big rectangle to be with single arrow by side (not like on the figure with two arrows by side), and then divide it to 4 identical smaller rectangles ?

Comment: Yes! The goal is to divide it into 4 smaller rectangles each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I defined a command `\arrowManifold`, witch creates a `tikzpicture` with the arrows by using nested `foreach`-loops.
To divide one rectangle into 4 smaller rectangles there is calculated the power of 2 for the argument of `\arrowManifold`, using the `calculator`-package.

In the document the command is called for different recursion levels.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\arrowManifold}[2][1]{
    % #1 = scale
    % #2 = recursion
    \POWER{2}{#2}{\n}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',scale=#1*1/\n]
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., \n} {
        \foreach \x in {1, ..., \n} {
            \draw (\x-.1,\y+.9) -- (\x-.9,\y+.9);
            \draw (\x-.9,\y+.9) -- (\x-.9,\y+.1);
            \draw (\x-.9,\y+.1) -- (\x-.1,\y+.1);
            \draw (\x-.1,\y+.1) -- (\x-.1,\y+.9);
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {0, ..., 3} {
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \arrowManifold[3]{\i}
        \caption{Arrow-manifold \i}
    \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Lindenmayer systems solution, combined with `show path construction` decoration that draws all segments in the l-system path slightly moved on the left, slightly shortened and with an arrow.

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
  \tikzset{
      % use of `show path construction` to draw all edges of the Lindenmayer systems
      edges/.style = {
        decoration={
          show path construction,
          lineto code={
            \draw[-latex,#1] ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!.1!35:(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
                          -- ($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)!.1!-35:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$);
          }
        },
        decorate
      },
      % define the Lindenmayer systems
      l-rect/.style = {
        l-system={rule set={F ->F[+F+F+F]f,f->ff}, axiom=F, order=#1,step=1cm},
      }
  }
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path[edges=purple]
                     l-system [l-rect=1]
        [xshift=2cm] l-system [l-rect=2]
        [xshift=3cm] l-system [l-rect=3];
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]